# Help setting up a static IP on ubuntu server 16.10

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

Hello I am attempting to setup a static IP on a vps running ubuntu server 16.10 runing on oracle VirtualBox with a NAT adapter

I have followed some guides online and I have tried going into

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

inside of my network interfaces this is what I have put

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

The broadcast I put as the same IP as the address because I only have static I dont have access to the internal IP as when I am on my windows machine It shows my public IP

once I have that set up I run curl ipech.net/plain ; echo
it says

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipecho.net
```

I also can not ping any IP address any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you setting networking on VirtualBox or VPS (host)?

Comment: i am using Virtual Box